# Userscript: EventListener doesn't listen (on a tab showing a remote pdf)

Tags: javascript, userscripts

I made a code to retrieve (and format) the URL of any webpage.

But it doesn't work for remote pdf opened in a tab in Edge (chromium)  PDF reader.

So I made the code below to select the URL (by pressing <kbd>F4</kbd>) and copy it (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>).

But no matter where I click, the userscript never catches the keyboardEvent (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>) I use to call the command.

I also tried with `document.onkeydown = function() { alert("key down") }` which works on all regular websites but not on tabs with (remote) pdf.

How to solve this issue?

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     Get url of pdf open in browser
// @namespace
// @description
// @include     *
// @version     1
// @grant       GM_notification
// ==/UserScript==

window.addEventListener("keydown", dispatchkeyboard);

function dispatchkeyboard(key) {
    if (key.keyCode == 66 && key.altKey) { ///66 = b   https://keycode.info/
   alert(window.location.href)  // I get the alert on all regular website, but not when the tab is Edge pdf reader
        if (window.location.href.includes("chrome-extension")) {
  

    // send F4
            element.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent("keydown", {
                key: "F4",
                code: "F4", 
                which: 115,

            }));
    // send Ctrl + C 
            element.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent("keydown", {
                key: "c",
                keyCode: 67, 
                code: "Keyc", 
                which: 67,
                shiftKey: false, 
            }));




        }

    }
}
```

A random pdf [link](https://samf.ku.dk/pcs/pdf_filer/Samlet_study_skills_med_nyt_navn_2010.pdf) for those who want to try

Answer (score 0):

Just formated and cleaned your code...

```js
window.addEventListener("keydown",
    (key)=>{
        if (key.keyCode == 66 && key.altKey) {
            alert(window.location.href);
            if (window.location.href.includes("chrome-extension")) {
                element.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent("keydown", {key: "F4", code: "F4", which: 115}));
                element.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent("keydown", { key: "c", keyCode: 67, code: "Keyc",which: 67,shiftKey: false}));
            }
        }
    }
);
```

On **Chrome** via the provided [pdf link](https://samf.ku.dk/pcs/pdf_filer/Samlet_study_skills_med_nyt_navn_2010.pdf). I get this (this is due to the pdf loading via the chrome pdf internal extension as you can see the `window.location`

[image]

If I reuse this in **Firefox** I get

[image]

If i reuse this in **Edge** I get

[image]

So after further investigation, it seems that you should force users to use firefox, as firefox is the only browser that seems to support what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thanks but I need to stay on edge. (And I tried your code on edge but it doesn't throw the alert on the pdf tab).

Comment: you did press "b" and left "alt"?  left and righ alts have different values

Comment: Yes I did (I apologize for the delay)